# Migrate Postgresql 8.4 to 9.1

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I currently run Postgres 8.4 on Centos 6. I need to migrate to Postgres 9.1 on a Windows machine. I have my reasons for this...Anyway, what is the best way to move the data from one DB to another without interrupting service and losing any of the functionality particularly with PostGIS? The PostGIS version (2.0) that installs with 9.1 has some features that I want to take advantage of but at the same time I don't want to lose any of the features in 8.4. Can anyone provide some insight in to this?

Comment: Question isn't specific. Something prevents you from maling backup and try on 9.1? In most cases it is not a big deal. Try SOMETHING first )

Comment: Well, I've seen pg_dump/pg_restore and pg_upgrade. There is also seen hard upgrade which is why I wanted to ask which one the community thinks is the best approach. I can use OGR to do this too but it creates a set of pk's and geometry types that I am not currently using. I just wanted some opinion from people who may have done this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the only thing that will let you upgrade without downtime is a trigger-based replication system such as [Slony-I](http://slony.info/).